# AWS EC2 userdata giving "No such file or directory" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data

I am trying to run the following in my userdata while creating ec2.

```
sudo yum update -y 
sudo amazon-linux-extras install ansible2 -y
ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -f /home/ssm-user/.ssh/id_rsa -N ''
```

However, I am getting the following error -

```
Saving key "/home/ssm-user/.ssh/id_rsa" failed: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this ?

Comment: Does the `/home/ssm-user/` directory exist? How about the `/home/ssm-user/.ssh` directory? You will probably need to create them before creating a file in that location.

Comment: creating the .ssh directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your host does not have /home/ssm-user/.ssh/ directory.
Run `mkdir -p /home/ssm-user/.ssh` before ssh-keygen.